# i18n localizing phone numbers, addresses, currency

Tags: java, internationalization

I'm wondering if anyone has ever come across an open-source package that would provide implementations of date formats, phone number formats, addresses (and zip code/postal) and currencies, etc based on the country locale.

So for a Country code, the i18n library would return a specific implementation for the defined types mentionned.

I would like to see the JDK provide that need.

I would be willing to participate in such a project if anyone want's to do it.

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localized date and currency formatting is part of the standard API. Relevant starting points are the classes `java.text.DateFormat` and `java.text.NumberFormat`.

If you need support for locales beyond what's offered from the standard API or more detailed functionality, you may find what you need in the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) libraries.

For phone number formatting, you might be able to use [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) from Google. For some countries, the formatting and classification rules are however incomplete or extremely outdated. It might be worth taking a look at, but may not be exactly what you're looking for. AFAIK, there are however no better solutions available.

For address formatting, you may be able to use Google's [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). It is not a downloadable library, but an online service. You can input a free-format address and the service will return a properly formatted address in the `formatted_address` field.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will check into the ICU libraries but I need something downloadable.